# What’s wrong with saying “he has his mind in the right mindset?”

Tags: american-english, north-american-english

My friend says its gramatically incorrect, what do you guys think?

Comment: It's *grammatically* correct, but it's not something native speakers would say. Perhaps it's a "malapropism" for *He has his **heart in the right place** / His heart's in the right place*.

Comment: to have a mind and you have a mindset but having your mind in a mindset is redundancy.

Comment: I see,  I’m getting mixed responses from different sources. Thank you guys for clarifying

Comment: Hello, Bryan. There are plenty of Google hits for "in the right mindset”, but I can't find any where the PP is used to describe '[his] mind'. It's just not used that way. It (and the related ... _into_ ...) is usually used to refer directly to a person (He's not in the right mindset / She got into the right mindset ...). It's more meaningful to say that 'it's unidiomatic' rather than 'it's ungrammatical'. Probably equally serious errors.

Comment: It's really simple, the word "mindset" already indicates you're talking about the mind. There's no need to further emphasize this because it will sound weird despite being grammatically correct. I think it could even be considered a pleonasm (a phrase like "cash money", "true fact" or "LAN network")

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I don't see what his heart has to do with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For informal speech, this phrase is okay.  For formal speech, or for something written, such as a persuasive letter or a term paper, it would be better to avoid combining "mind" and "mindset" in close proximity.  The awkwardness would be kind of like writing, "Next, set the new combination on the combination lock."

Oxford's definition of *mindset*:

> The established set of attitudes held by someone.

To be in the *right mindset* means to have a helpful mental attitude.  For example: if you  go to college thinking it's good enough to show up to class and spend an hour a day on homework, you're not in the right *mindset*.  Meaning, you aren't looking at the college experience the right way -- you're not thinking about it right.

The simple correction to "he has his mind in the right mindset" would be "he has the right mindset."

Comment: @JasonBassford - Oh jeesh, I guess I wasn't in the right mindset.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

"He has his mind in the right mindset" is not grammatically wrong but it is an awkward sentence.

Either "He is **in his right mind**" or "He has the right **mindset**" would work. Putting the two together creates an awkward sentence.

**in (one's) right mind**

> Thinking soundly; rational. Usually used to set up a context in which any sane person would or could do, say, or think a certain thing.
>   [Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+your+right+mind)

**mindset**

> noun
>   [usually in singular]
>   The established set of attitudes held by someone.
>   ‘the region seems stuck in a medieval mindset’
>   [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/mindset)

Comment: I agree with what you said about mindset, but "in one's right mind" has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: *"He is in his right mind"* generally means *"he hasn't gone insane,"* not that he is in the right mindset to do some specific task. What the Free Dictionary means is that it's generally used in phrases like *"anybody in their right mind,"* which means *"anybody who isn't batsh!t crazy."*

Comment: @aparente001 I agree, the question had nothing to do with  "in one's right mind". The question had nothing to do with any definitions at all. It was a grammar question and I offered an answer - the grammar is fine but awkward.

Comment: @DavidD - We may have to agree to disagree.  I think that the phrase "in one's right mind" has as much relevance to this question as *male pattern baldness* or *mindfulness training* would.  (I.e., none.)  But I do agree with what you said about *mindset*.